# How do I prevent QGIS error messages from vanishing?

Tags: qgis, error, display, logging

I get error messages with some layers, but I can only see their first line and they disappear before I get the chance to read them.

How can I prevent this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also show all logged message by displaying the log panel.

Go to the `view` menu then `panels` and finally `log messages`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are [QgsMessageBar elements](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html#showing-messages-the-qgsmessagebar-class) displayed in the message bar, they have a "pause" button with a timer on the left.  Just click on it and the message will stay.